# How do I create and consume a nuget package that only contains assets?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuspec

I have the following `.csproj` for a very simple package I'm trying to create:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageId>my-nuget-package</PackageId>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <NoBuild>true</NoBuild>
    <IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="**/*.graphql">
        <Pack>true</Pack>
        <PackagePath></PackagePath>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The basic idea is that I would like to come up with a versioned way of distributing my `.graphql` schema files to projects. Overall, this generates a `.nupkg` file that contains my schema in it, but when I go to add it to a project, I'm not sure how to reference the file from code.